# Паттерн прототип, конструктор копирование

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, prototype

В чем заключается смысл использования паттерна прототип над конструктором копирование.
Пример

```
obj = new ConcretePrototype();
```

---

```
obj2 = new ConcretePrototype(obj);

obj2 = obj.Clone();
```

---

В чем преимущество прототипа?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что есть преимущества?

Comment: вот и мне интересно